# What Python libraries are used in the script to scrape product titles and image URLs from an Amazon page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-2.7

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

# URL of the Amazon product page you want to scrape
url = "https://www.amazon.com/sheets-pillowcases/b/ref=dp_bc_aui_C_3?ie=UTF8&node=1063274"

# Send a GET request to the URL
response = requests.get(url)

# Create a BeautifulSoup object with the response content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

# Find all the product containers on the page
product_containers = soup.find_all("div", class_="s-include-content-margin")

# Iterate over each product container
for container in product_containers:
    # Find the title of the product
    title_element = container.find("span", class_="a-text-normal")
    if title_element is not None:
        title = title_element.text.strip()
        print("Product:", title)

    # Find the image URL of the product
    image_element = container.find("img", class_="s-image")
    if image_element is not None:
        image_url = image_element["src"]
        print("Image URL:", image_url)

        # Download the image
        image_name = title.replace(" ", "_") + ".jpg"
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, image_name)
        print("Image downloaded:", image_name)

    print("-----------------------------------")
```

Please explain this so that can have the better Idea. I am new to this. Thanks in advance

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` is a parser library for HTML and XML used in scraping the web pages, whereas `requests` and `urllib` are used to creating requests to the webpages hence the  names.
your question should be more specific.

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Necessary Header so that Amazon allows you to access their webpage
PRODUCT_URL = "PRODUCT URL"
Accept_Language = "en-US,en;q=0.9"
User_Agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36"
Headers = {
    "Accept-Language": Accept_Language,
    "User-Agent": User_Agent
}

# Get the source code using requests
response = requests.get(url=PRODUCT_URL, headers=Headers)

# Parse the source code using bs4
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

# Get the title element and extract the text inside it of the product
# <title>Product Title</title>
#        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
product_name = soup.find("title").getText()
print(product_name)

# Get the image tag with id "landingImage" and extract the src attribute
# <img id="landingImage" src="image_link">
#                             ^^^^^^^^^^
product_img = soup.find("img", {"id": "landingImage"})
print(product_img["src"])
```